# Reading CoreData from iCloud works on iPhone but not on iPad - deleted

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, core-data

Deleted by owner. Questioned phrased poorly.

Comment: You mention Core Data a few times but your code doesn't seem to relate to Core Data at all. Specifically this looks like you're using the iCloud file API, which is not how you sync Core Data via iCloud.

Comment: You are right I didn't show my CoreData code snippets. I will add it here and also correct my problems.

Comment: You say that you "...wrote the CoreData files to iCloud". Are you talking about moving the Core Data persistent store file to iCloud? I can't tell what you're moving from your code, but that's what it sounds like.